# Как добавить собственный префикс ко всем подписям к изображениям постов WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Хочу добавить собственный префикс ко всем подписям к изображениям постов WordPress.
Вставляю в файл functions.php активной темы такой код

```
add_filter( 'image_add_caption_text', 'add_custom_prefix', 10, 2 );
function add_custom_prefix( $caption, $id ) {
    $prefix = 'Фото: ';
    return $prefix . $caption;
}
```

Но префикс не добавляется.

Подскажите в чем ошибка?
И какое есть решение для этой задачи?

Comment: Это код и не добавит "ко всем". Он будет добавлять только для новых, причём вставленных шорткодом, а не в гутенберге. Тебе нужно добавить к уже существующим или что значит "ко всем"?